# Powershell: adding arrays in a function does not work

Tags: powershell

I need to make a script that writes users and certain attributes to a csv file. Before I lookup all the attributes I want to collect all users from the different sources in an array.
I lookup the users from a group and add them in an array. I add this array to another array, so I can add the users found in an OU to that same array. However, every time I call this function (that adds the array to the other array) the array is empty.

I created a script that has the same issue but uses text files:

```
$array3 = @()
$Array = @()

function get-start {
    $text = Get-Content -Path C:\Data\text.txt
    foreach ($Line in $Text)
    {
        If ($Line -eq "text1.txt")
        {
            Get-Text1
        }
        ElseIf ($Line -eq "text2.txt")
        {
            Get-Text2
        }
    }
}

function Get-Text1{
    $array = Get-Content -Path C:\Data\text1.txt
    Write-Host "Content of Text1.txt is $array"
    Add-Arrays
}
function Get-Text2{
    $array = Get-Content -Path C:\Data\text2.txt
    Write-Host "Content of Text2.txt is $array"
    Add-Arrays
}

Function Add-Arrays {
    Write-Host "Content of array3 is $array3"
    $array3 = $array3 + $array
    Write-Host "Content of array3 now is $array3"
}

Get-Start
```

Outcome of the script is:

```
Content of Text1.txt is Red Blue Green Yellow Purple Black White
Content of array3 is
Content of array3 now is Red Blue Green Yellow Purple Black White
Content of Text2.txt is Apple Pear Banana Pineapple Peach
Content of array3 is
Content of array3 now is Apple Pear Banana Pineapple Peach
```

The function Add-Arrays works, however, when it is called a second time (to add the content of text2) $array3 is empty again. How do I prevent it from getting empty?

I tried Arraylist but this does not work. I also tried to write the array to a temporary array and use the write-variable but the outcome is the same.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I haven't tracked this down, but it looks like a scope problem.  It looks like there iss a local variable $array3 inside the function, and the value is not passed to the less local copy of $array3 defined inside your script.  Modifying global variables inside a function is likely to lead to unmaintainable code downstream.  Fixing this would require to to rewrite most of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
The array must be Global.
The function Add-Arrays must look like this:

```
Function Add-Arrays {
Write-Host "Content of array3 is $array3"
$Global:array3 += $array
Write-Host "Content of array3 now is $array3"
}
```

Comment: Adding to an array with `+=` is very costly and time consuming because the entire array needs to get rebuilt in memory each time. Better use a [List object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) like: `$array3 = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]` and add to it using `$array3.AddRange([string[]]$array)`